# SCSS Interpolation in mixin call

Tags: css, sass

I want to make a simple interpolation into a mixin call:

```
$models: "square", "square-green", "circle";
$services: "facebook", "twitter", "linkedin", "gplus", "feed";

@each $model in $models {
    @include all-#{$model}-sprites;
    @each $service in $services {
            #{$model}-#{$service} {
                &:hover{ @extend .#{$model}-#{$service}-hover;};
            }
    }
}
```

> error sass/soboo2.scss (Line 14: Invalid CSS after "  @include all-":
>   expected "}", was "#{$model}-sprites;")

I've also tried a few syntax variations that come across internet:

```
@include all-"#{$model}"-sprites;
@include [all-#{$model}-sprites];
@include [all-"#{$model}"-sprites];
@include all-$model-sprites;
```

Doesn't work... any suggestions??

Comment: It would not surprise me if variable interpolation doesn't work on mixins/includes, since variable variables is not allowed.  I doubt there is a solution for you.

Comment: Ended removing the mixins from my loop and using them one-by-one. Thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to do mixin's interpolation is to write the call like that :

```
@include all-#{$model}-sprites(); // parenthesis are optional if 0 arguments given
```

However, you should take a look to this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16153447/10680340