# Style switching by interpolating a variable value

Tags: sass

I'm trying to create a variable that will switch styles by changing it's value.

something like:

```
$style: 1;

$color1: #f60;
$color2: #096;

$color: $color#{style};

.a{
  color: $color;
}
```

Unfortunately the result is: `Undefined variable: "$color".`

Could someone explain to me why this doesn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass Interpolation challenge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152547/sass-interpolation-challenge)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like this feature got added in SASS 3.3

> When we released Sass 3.02, we added support for SCSS, which meant we had to actually parse all the selectors in the document. This meant that you couldn't just plop the parent selector, &, anywhere in a selector. Overall this was an improvement: it caught more errors and encouraged users to write more flexible mixins.
>   Unfortunately, it also made one important use-case harder. With the rise in popularity of BEM, OOCSS, and SMACSS, people became more and more interested in adding suffixes to classes. When using Sass, they wanted to write mixins to do this, and the restrictions on & made that very hard to do.
>   In Sass 3.3, we're loosening these restrictions. You can now write &-suffix (or &_suffix, or even &suffix if you really want) and Sass will make it work. If this fails to apply—for example, if & is * —Sass will print a helpful error message.

[source](http://blog.sass-lang.com/posts/184094-sass-33-is-released)