# SASS - Creating a new $variable and its value into a new $variable

Tags: variables, sass, interpolation

What i'am trying to achieve is, taking each $variable and put them though a function that mixes white and the color $var making it a bit lighter.

i'am not able to do this due to my lack of understanding of sass so far.

so the questions are:

why i'am i able to make $ on my interpolation when i'am able to make it a class?

is where a better way of achieving this?

```
$red     : #F4493C;
$blue    : #2196F3;
$white   : #FFFFFF;
$red-50  : #ffcccc; // <-- this is what it should result in...

$colors:(
  red,
  blue
);

/* how the function should work
@function colortint($color, $white, $amount){
  @return mix($color, $white, $amount);
}
*/

@function colortint($color, $white){
  @return mix($color, $white, 20%);
}

body {
  background-color: colortint($red, $white);  
}

@each $color in $colors {
.#{$color} {
   background-color: colortint($color, $white); // giving it a classworks
  }
}

/* this is what i want
@each $color in $colors {
  ${$color}-50 : colortint($color, $white, 20%); // why can't i make it a variable
}
*/
```

Comment: As to making this specific case simpler, SASS has lighten() and darken() functions built-in - though that may not solve your actual problem :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass Interpolation of Mixin, Function, and Variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152547/sass-interpolation-of-mixin-function-and-variable-names)

Comment: The problem with lighten() and darken() is that is its not linear, by mixing in white color you can achieve a linear change. and no its not really my problem :)

Comment: Yip you are right cimmanon. thanks :) damn it would be a nice feature though.